# Writing my own reverse array function without defining a new empty array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function which reverses the elements of an array without defining a new empty array in the function.

```
let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function remove(array, index) {
return array.slice(0, index).concat(array.slice(index + 1));
}

function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    let removedCharacter = array[i];
    array = array.concat(removedCharacter);
    array = remove(array, i);
  } 
    return array;
}
```

When I console.log(reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue)) I am getting the reverse order of [5, 4, 3, 2, 1].

However when I try to just do reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue) and then console.log(arrayValue), I am getting [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] which is the value defined at the beginning.

Is there a way of updating the arrayValue binding in the function and then when it is console.log outside the function, it is showing the reversed order?

Comment: Your `remove` function isn't in-place at all. An in-place solution would not reassign the `array` variable, and it would not need to return a value. An in-place solution would actually *mutate* the passed-in array by swapping its elements with each other. Please try that and show us your attempt. Think non-functional.

Comment: The solution for this exercise had the return statement at the end so I was assuming that my function had to return something as well.  Thank you for the clarification on in-place.

Answer (score 0):

```
// show cases of even and odd lengths
const x = [1,2,3,4];
const y = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (let i = 0; i < x.length / 2; i++) {
  const tmp = x[i];

  x[i] = x[x.length - 1 - i];
  x[x.length - 1 - i] = tmp;
}

for (let i = 0; i < y.length / 2; i++) {
  const tmp = y[i];

  y[i] = y[y.length - 1 - i];
  y[y.length - 1 - i] = tmp;
}

console.log(x);
// [4, 3, 2, 1]

console.log(y);
// [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The MDN docs for Array's [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) methods explain that these methods return new arrays, rather than modifying the existing arrays. If you are looking for a built-in Array method for modifying arrays, [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will do the job. However, it's going to be more complicated to implement this using `splice` than to just use a `for` loop as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could just swap values symmetrically around the midpoint of the array, like

```js
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
const len = arr.length;
for(let i = 0; i < len/2; i++){
  let temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[len-1-i];
  arr[len-1-i] = temp;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This was the answer that I gave 30 minutes ago

Answer (score -1):

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
 for (let i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
  const oppositeArrayIndex = array.length - (i + 1);
  const oppasiteArrayValue = array[oppositeArrayIndex];
  array[oppositeArrayIndex] = array[i];
  array[i] = oppasiteArrayValue;
 }
}
```

Comment: I disagree, this code is more self-documenting thanks to variable naming than the one from the other answer, that you didn't mark as "low quality"

Comment: its just suggestion. generally code only answers will go to low quality queues by SO(its not me who will mark as low or high quality). it came to my review thats why suggested. hope you understood now.Thanks